# Phonegap 1.0.0 Zoom issue

Tags: java, android, html, cordova, android-emulator

I have a basic Phonegap Application which is having 2 pages `index.html` and `index1.html` which are having links to each other.

I enabled zoom and tested. When I am on Page 1 zoom works properly When i traverse to page 2 or I return back to page 1 it does not zoom.

About a year Earlier when I was working on Froyo when I traversed from Page 1 to Page 2 and zoomed it worked fine. (Did not try the reverse)

I would like to know if this is Android Phonegap issue or Android Platform Issue

`Current Device : HTC Desire Z`

`Current Phonegap Version : 1.0.0`

`Current Platform : Gingerbread 2.3.3`

My Code :

[index](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1135516/)

[index 1](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1135514/)

[Main Activity](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1135517/)

I would also like to know if its possible for me to zoom on the Emulator? Someone told me that its possible to do so by using CTRL + MOUSE 1 but it does not work at my end. The only difference is they are using Cordova 2.0.0 while i am using Phonegap 1.0.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this used to work flawlessly on `Froyo` and is giving issues with `Gingerbread` and later releases.

I am closing this question as I feel the Cordova Java Script API's seem to have an issue with the Operating Systems I mentioned above.

If someone from Cordova could assert this issue. He may be the right person to actually adress the same.